# Can't click button in pop up UI Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Hi I am trying to click on a button within a pop up("klant aanpassen"), I already tried allot of options including `ActionChains` but I just don't get it to work. Right now this is my script:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Acties"]').click()

time.sleep(2)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class='_2f9OE _2nG1g yG7LA mekFH _2zshv _2enAb _2g-UE iyvDv _17-jo']"))).click()
```

The first code does the right thing, open up the UI(PopUp)
[image]

The second line of code give's me the following error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:/Users/Marnix Bolier/Desktop/TLinputter.py", line 52
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Acties"]').click()
DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_xpath is deprecated. Please use find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath) instead
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Marnix Bolier/Desktop/TLinputter.py", line 54, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class='_2f9OE _2nG1g yG7LA mekFH _2zshv _2enAb _2g-UE iyvDv _17-jo']"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\Marnix Bolier\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I also tried the following line:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='_2f9OE _2nG1g yG7LA mekFH _2zshv _2enAb _2g-UE iyvDv _17-jo']").click()
```

That gives the following error:

```
line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Google Inspector (button highlighted in blue): [image]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here, Thanks.

Comment: Please share all your Selenium code and especially the link to the page you are working on (if possible) for minimal debugging

Comment: @Prophet Thanks for your answer i am not able to share the rest of my code since it does not have any more selenium code besides the imports and `driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Marnix Bolier/Desktop/driver/chromedriver.exe')` i rather not share the rest of my code since it has credentials and specific url id's. the page is behind a login screen so that is not going to help either.

Comment: I see. But without seeing that page I'm not sure we can help

Comment: @Prophet anyway i can share the page in a better way?

Comment: I'm not sure. can you check if `button[class='_2f9OE _2nG1g yG7LA mekFH _2zshv _2enAb _2g-UE iyvDv _17-jo']` is unique selector? maybe it will be better to use Xpath based on text, something like `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.,'Klant aanpassen')]"))).click()` ?

Comment: @Prophet you are a legend! the contains methode worked perfectly! i already tried a find by text, but ofcourse that didn't work. Thanks allot!

Comment: Great, if so I will give that as an answer with more explanations :)

Comment: @Prophet can i close the case? or do you want to add something before i do?

Comment: I think this question may be useful for future users, so we can leave it. And the answer, if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249694/discussion-between-marnix-bolier-and-prophet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locators like this CSS Selector `button[class='_2f9OE _2nG1g yG7LA mekFH _2zshv _2enAb _2g-UE iyvDv _17-jo']` are problematic since they based on too much class names. These class names may be dynamically changing per session and per page state.
This locator can also be not unique.
What we can try here is text based XPath like this:

```py
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.,'Klant aanpassen')]"))).click()
```

This locator looks more stable and unique.